# how to use nested copy in Arm Template

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am creating multiple resource policies (backup policies in Recovery Service Vault) for multiple environments. I was able to create them for one environment, how do i replicate them using nested copy for QA.

They will have policy name as AZR-QA-SQL-1Hour-Policy-001

Any help is appreciated.

```
  "variables": {
    "sqlDevPolicyName": [
      "[concat('AZR-DEV-SQL-1HOUR-POLICY-001')]",
      "[concat('AZR-DEV-SQL-4HOUR-POLICY-001')]",
      "[concat('AZR-DEV-SQL-8HOUR-POLICY-001')]"
    ]
    }
  }

"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults",
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-10",
      "name": "[parameters('vaultName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "RS0",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-10",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('vaultName'), '/', variables('sqlPolicyName')[copyIndex()])]",
      "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/', parameters('vaultName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "policies",
        "count": "[length(variables('sqlDevPolicyName'))]"
      },
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "backupManagementType": "AzureWorkload",
        "protectedItemsCount": 0,
        "settings": {
          "isCompression": false,
          "issqlcompression": false,
          "timeZone": "[parameters('timeZone')]"
        },
        "subProtectionPolicy": [
          {
            "policyType": "Full",
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
              "weeklySchedule": {
                "daysOfTheWeek": [
                  "Sunday"
                ],
                "retentionDuration": {
                  "count": 15,
                  "durationType": "Weeks"
                },
                "retentionTimes": "[parameters('scheduleRunTimes')]"
              }
            },
```

Comment: can you show your code for the existing one?

Comment: i am not able to add the code for resources, its giving me error code is too long. any suggestions on how i can show the code

Comment: you only need to show the code for the resource you are trying to "multiply", but let me show you a generalized example. this is basically it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-recovery-services-backup-classic-resource-manager-vms/azuredeploy.json

Comment: i have added part of code for resources that i need to multiply.  The policy name changes to AZR-QA-SQL-1HOUR-POLICY-001

Comment: `"copy":
 {

        "name": "policies",

        "count": "[length(variables('sqlDevPolicyName'))]"

},`

How do i use nested copy to say variables('sqlQAPolicyName)

Comment: ok, i dont really understand what is your question, unfortunately and I need to go to sleep soon. if you can maybe explain what you need in another words, i can wake up tomorrow and try and answer that ;)

Comment: Sure no worries :) 

So basically i need to create same thing for QA  which means should i create a second variable for QA as shown below and can i use the existing resources which is creating Dev policies and would also create policies for the below QA policies. 

`"sqlQAPolicyName": 
[
      "[concat('AZR-QA-SQL-1HOUR-POLICY-001')]",
      "[concat('AZR-QA-SQL-4HOUR-POLICY-001')]",
      "[concat('AZR-QA-SQL-8HOUR-POLICY-001')]"`

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of what you are saying you need to do this:

```
"variables": {
  "sqlQAPolicyName": [ // dont need concat() here
    "AZR-QA-SQL-1HOUR-POLICY-001",
    "AZR-QA-SQL-4HOUR-POLICY-001",
    "AZR-QA-SQL-8HOUR-POLICY-001"
  ]
},
"resources": [
  {
    same thing here, just need to create it two times, as you now have 2 sets of resources.
    and you need to use your QA variable to create backup policies for QA
    ...
  } 
]
```

at least this is how i see it

Comment: yep that's correct. ah ok i need to create two resources thats what i am planning to do. just wanted to see if there another way to do the same thing using nested  copy or similar

Comment: another approach would be to use parameters (not variables) and use the same template to deploy 2 sets of resources based on the input (which looks more logical)